Filter data range with multiple criteria for rows and columns and ignore the criteria if it is empty
  |   A   |B| C|D|  E  |  F  |  G  |  H  |I|  J  |K|    L   |    M   |N|   O    |   P    |   Q    |
--|-------|-|--|-|-----|-----|-----|-----|-|-----|-|--------|--------|-|--------|--------|--------|-
1 |       | |  | |2024 |2024 |2025 |2025 | |     | |RowCrit1|RowCrit2| |ColCrit1|ColCrit2|ColCrit3|
2 |       | |  | | HY1 | HY2 | HY1 | HY2 | |     | |    2025|     HY1| | Brand A|      P1|   Type1|
3 |       | |  | |     |     |     |     | |     | |        |        | | Brand C|      P3|   Type4|
4 |Brand A| |P1| | 500 |  70 |  60 |  80 | |Type1| |        |        | | Brand D|        |        |    
5 |Brand A| |P1| | 100 |  47 | 300 | 100 | |Type4| |        |        | |        |        |        |
6 |Brand A| |P2| | 800 |  21 | 200 | 360 | |Type4| |        |        | |Results |        |        |
7 |Brand B| |P1| |  90 |  56 | 150 | 578 | |Type2| |        |        | |    60  |        |        |
8 |Brand C| |P4| |  45 | 700 | 790 | 800 | |Type2| |        |        | |   300  |        |        |
9 |Brand C| |P2| | 600 | 150 |  40 |  10 | |Type2| |        |        | |   980  |        |        |
10|Brand D| |P1| | 900 |  90 | 980 | 453 | |Type1| |        |        | |        |        |        |
11|Brand D| |P1| | 125 | 854 | 726 | 850 | |Type2| |        |        | |        |        |        |
12|Brand D| |P3| |  70 | 860 | 614 | 140 | |Type3| |        |        | |        |        |        |
13|Brand D| |P4| | 842 | 250 |  85 | 215 | |Type2| |        |        | |        |        |        |
14|Brand E| |P3| | 300 | 324 | 450 | 430 | |Type4| |        |        | |        |        |        |


I want to filter the range E1:J14 based on the row criteria in Cell L2 and M2 and on the column criteria in Range O2:O4, P2:P4 and Q2:Q4.
In the example above I am able to get the correct results in Range O7:O10 with this formula:
=LET(a;COUNTIF(O2:O4;A3:A14);b;COUNTIF(P2:P4;C3:C14);c;COUNTIF(Q2:Q4;J3:J14);FILTER(FILTER(E3:H14;(E1:H1=L2)*(E2:H2=M2);"");IFS(SUM(a)=0;b;SUM(b)=0;SUM(c)=0;1;a*b*c);""))


However, my target is to only include the column criteria in case they are not empty. If they are empty they should be ignored. Therefore, the results should look like this:
Example 1: Only ColCrit1 is empty = 60,300,980,450 
Example 2: Only ColCrit2 is empty = 60,300,200,980 
Example 3: ColCrit2 and ColCrit3 is empty = 60,300,200,790,40,980,726,614,85 
Example 4: ColCrit1 and ColCrit3 is empty = 60,300,150,980,726,614,450 
....... and so on.
(Side Note: The row criteria will never be empty)

The current formula that I am using only works correctly for some of the cases. 
How do I have to modify it to make it work for all of them?

I really hope you will get it this time. Trying my best to make it as painless as possible.....
=LET(
    a, COUNTIF(O2:O4, A4:A14) + AND(O2:O4 = ""),
    b, COUNTIF(P2:P4, C4:C14) + AND(P2:P4 = ""),
    c, COUNTIF(Q2:Q4, J4:J14) + AND(Q2:Q4 = ""),
    FILTER(FILTER(E4:H14, (E1:H1 = L2) * (E2:H2 = M2), ""), a * b * c, "")
)

Briefly explaining below formula:
=COUNTIF(O2:O4, A4:A14) + AND(O2:O4 = "")
For each value in column A, it returns 1 if ColumnA is listed in ColCrit1 or ColCrit1 is empty, otherwise, it returns zero.
ColCrit1 empty:

ColCrit1 non-empty:

The same applies to ColCrit2, ColCrit3.
